# what is the most efficient and safe method to save a short array on html?

Tags: html, arrays, perl, cgi, persistence

I'm trying to make a website to serve as the interface between a plotting program and the user input file. The plotting program needs several parameters, which I could allow the user to enter using input tag. But the plotting program needs user input on the legend for distinguishing the values in the input file as well, namely the range(boundary) of value and the corresponding color for this range. I made a fieldset containing the required input elements for one range. When user click "Add another range",  the content of the fieldset is cleared so as to be ready for the new input. And the previously entered input is stored in a table below as a new row. Beside this row, there is a "delete" button.

As this website is aimed for multiple users, this information should be also exclusive for the corresponding user. Could someone please tell me what approach should I use? The plotting program is written using perl, and I'm using CGI for this website. 
And this approach should allow the html part to access the current values in the array, so I could display the entered ranges in the table dynamically. This approach should also allow the deletion/modification/addition of such entered range information. i'm thinking of a temporary database. But I only need the final version of all the range info in a string, so I can send it to the CGI program and organize it to be the correct format to be inputted into the perl plotting program.

Any help or hint is greatly appreciated! I'm a newbie to this area. Thank you very much for your time and help in advance!

Answer (score 5):

JSON is pretty universal these days. Use that. Many new database systems like MongoDB use JSON as a native storage format.

Most server-side languages can consume and produce JSON easily. JSON allows structured data, so it can do more than simple arrays.

JSON is also very fast on the browser (compared to XML), being a native JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

If the data will be purely in Perl, then FreezeThaw or Storable are the things to use. If your data is simple, then there is nothing wrong with Diodeus' answer of using JSON, but as things get complicated, those modules will be able to handle the complexities of Perl datastructures better.

Comment: yep, my data currently is just a set of range info separated by delimiter, so I may just start with JSON. But thank you very much for pointing that out!